# What are the impacts of disconnecting the Marketing Cloud business unit from one SFDC sandbox and connecting it to others?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

What are the impacts of disconnecting the Marketing Cloud from one SFDC sandbox and connecting it to others ? Apart from Sync Data Extensions, will there be any other changes/impacts ? Also, what happens to the emails, content blocks, automations and journeys ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically everything that has been set up using the connection will need to be re-done. This includes but may not be limited to:

- Synchronized Data Extensions will be removed and need to be configured again
- New Synchronized Data Extension will most likely have another postfix (e.g. Salesforce_Contact_1 instead of Salesforce_Contact)

  - you need to adapt all the Automations/SQL queries that reference those DEs
  - Filtered Data Extensions based on the Synchronized DEs won't work
  - Access to Synchronized Data Extensions via AMPscript in Emails and CloudPages needs to be adapted
- If you use Salesforce Data Events in Journey Builder, you need to re-create all of them in order for them to be connected to your new org. Changing the Entry event requires re-configuring all the decision splits, Salesforce Activities, Goal/Exit Criteria, etc.
- Tracking events won't be pushed to the old SF org afterwards.
- If a new connection is made, tracking for previous sends is not pushed to the new org.
- Triggered Sends will still be connected to the old org when disconnecting, so you need to deactivate them manually.
- The mapped business unit(s) and users need to be remapped

For help on disconnecting the account, also check out the documentation article ["Disconnect Account".](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_disconnect_account.htm&type=5)