# SFDC and SFMC are connected... if we now move to PersonAccounts, do we need to disconnect the platforms and reconnect after converting?

Tags: marketing-cloud-connect, person-accounts, data-model

We are looking to change the Data Model for SFDC from Accounts/Contacts to Person Accounts.
Currently, SFMC is connected to SFDC - but if the data model changes, do we need to disconnect the integration and reconnect after the SFDC data model is updated?

I reviewed this thread: [What are the impacts of disconnecting the Marketing Cloud business unit from one SFDC sandbox and connecting it to others?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297312/what-are-the-impacts-of-disconnecting-the-marketing-cloud-business-unit-from-one)  but it doesn't specifically address my use case.

Any suggestions?